# Swag is coming back! (indefinitely paused)

Tags: discussion, announcements, swag

### Update November 2023

Hi everyone. I realize it’s been a year and a half since we updated you all that swag was on pause. There have been a lot of moving pieces this year hence the delay in an official update. The TL/DR is that swag will remain on pause for the foreseeable future.

We had to pause swag last year in part due to staffing changes and in part due to changes in our vendors. We were hoping to have a vendor solution in place to make sending out swag an easy lift for the Community Management team and a foolproof process for community members to be able to submit their shipping info without PII being stored by a third-party vendor.

Unfortunately getting a vendor set up and a process to manage proved to be a cumbersome endeavor. In a time of limited resources, we are directing areas of funding to work that more directly supports our goals of focusing on maintaining and improving the experience on the Stack Exchange Network sites. Our team also doesn't have the bandwidth to currently manage a swag system. These three factors lead us to where we are at the moment. Our community swag program is going to remain paused for the foreseeable future.

I know that is disappointing and believe me, I wish we were in a position where we could be shipping swag yesterday. But we’re not. I don’t have a time frame for when/if swag will be back. If we are able to bring it back in the future we will update you.

---

### Update May 2022

I know everyone ([myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/943183/rosie) included) has been excited by the return of swag. I just wanted to give y'all a heads up that we're currently revamping our swag options and shipping process, so we have to put a temporary pause on sending swag out.

As soon as updates are in place, I'll let you all know and we'll work to retroactively ship swag to anyone who earned it during the interim. We're sorry for the temporary hiatus. Once everything is up and running again, we'll post an update here.

---

One of the things we enjoy doing at Stack Overflow is celebrating with you when you reach momentous events in our communities. Traditionally, we’ve celebrated by sending swag your way when you’ve reached a high reputation score or when you’ve been elected as a moderator to one of our great network communities. It’s been [some time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341194/) since we've been able to do this and I’m here to announce that we are actively restarting the sending of the swags!

There are 3 categories of folks that will be getting swag. Since shipping costs can be pretty significant, we’re going to do this in batches. We’re planning to retroactively award swag to everyone who would have received it since we stopped shipping, primarily to new high reputation users, new moderators, and contest winners. Then, once we are caught up, we will begin to once again send out swag to new first-time moderators and high rep users as they achieve these milestones.

I want to call out that some countries are very difficult for us to send items to and if yours is one of those, we will let you know. The list of countries can change so rather than putting them here, we’ll address it when we get your shipping information. Regardless, we’re going to make our best effort to send you your swag... we don’t want these items gathering dust on a shelf!

And now, the categories.

### High Reputation Members

There are two levels to this tier, one for reaching 100K and another for 250K in reputation points. Those who earned these levels starting from March 2019 will be eligible to receive their package of swag.

Those who earned 100K will receive:

- Branded T-shirt (SE or SO)
- Branded socks (SE or SO) - two styles available, you’ll get one selected randomly

Those who earned 250K will receive:

- Branded T-shirt (SE or SO)
- Branded socks (SE or SO) - two styles available, you’ll get one selected randomly
- Webcam cover
- Water bottle or tumbler (SE or SO)
- SE pop socket

### Moderators

For our distinguished and elected moderators, we also have some goodies we want to send you. We will start with those moderators who were elected starting from January 2019 to now and once we’ve completed sending those folks their swag, we will then continue with the entire moderator team and refresh each one of you with shiny and new goodies!

All moderators will receive:

- Moderator diamond hat
- T-shirt (SO or SE)
- Water bottle or tumbler

### Past Contest Winners

Back in 2018 we held a "[Stuff-a-way!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321399/announcing-our-amazing-2018-stuff-a-way/)" contest and asked folks to share accounts of goodwill where items were given to people to make someone's life better. We were able to send most of the participants their box of swag but there were some whom we still owe some goodies. We have a list of those folks and we're ready to send you the following items:

- SE socks - two styles available, you’ll get one selected randomly
- SE T-shirt
- Branded webcam cover
- SE pop socket
- Branded pen

### A Few Items

We were unable to get good photos of every item we’re planning on shipping mainly because these were created offsite. But, I did want to include some so you can get an idea of what we’re talking about. We’re really excited to be able to do this again and we hope you’ll be just as excited when you get your swag! We’d also appreciate it if you posted an answer with photos of the swag you receive for others to see.

**Stack Overflow tshirt** [image: SO-tshirt]

**Stack Exchange tshirt** [image: SE-tshirt]

**Stack Exchange pop socket** [image: SE-popsocket]

**Stack Overflow Socks**  [image: SO-Socks]

**Stack Exchange Socks**  [image: SE-socks]

### FAQs

**How will you know where to ship my goodies to?**

Everyone who is eligible to receive swag will receive an email from us giving details on how they can submit their address information and t-shirt size (in a GDPR-compliant fashion). These emails will be sent out over batches over the next few months and they will come from the *communityswag@stackoverflowsolutions.com* address. Once we are all caught up on the backlog, we will start once again sending swag to moderators and high rep users as they reach these milestones. We will update here as each new batch is sent out (if you think that you should have been included in a batch that was already sent, then [reach out to us](/contact) and we will try to make it right).

**Who will be doing the shipping?**

We are using a third-party vendor called Proforma to actually handle the shipping. Your shipping address will be shared with them for the sole purpose of sending you your swag.

**Is there a way for users to purchase swag?**

Unfortunately, we are unable to offer swag for purchase at this time. If this changes, we will let you know.

---

### Update May 2021

Our first wave of emails have gone out and they're coming from our *communityswag@stackoverflowsolutions.com* address. We're using this address because we don't have third-party emailing tools tied to the stackoverflow.com domain. So, if you get one, know that it's from us!

---

### Update June 2021

The first of the shipments has been made and we wanted to give you a head's up on some changes we've had to make in what we're able to send out.

I’ve spent the past several weeks planning the packages for our swag shipments and I discovered that some items were bundled for shipments in groups of 5 and up. This meant that if we requested something to be sent to you, you’d get 5 or 10 of them (depending on the item and the design). This was beneficial for our marketing team since they normally send large orders of items to conferences and events. However, for us, there’s no use in sending you 12 mugs at a time. Not only is this unreasonable, it’s also very expensive!

I was able, however, to reorder most swag items and inventory them individually but having to reorder these items cut into our overall budget. In order to stick with our timeline and our desire to send you swag, we’ve opted to remove only the stickers from the packages to reduce production times and save enough to include even more people in this. I've made corrections to package lists above and removed the stickers for now. Everything else will stay!

Also, the second wave of emails will be sent out in a few weeks!

Comment: Anything for past moderators?  SE is awesome by the way!  I'm not just saying that to get free swag.

Comment: I'll take my algebra notes with that pen you're offering :D

Comment: I want to send swag to every single moderator once we send it to the "newest" additions to the team. I'll have more on that after we get the initial queues taken care of!

Comment: *you’ll get one selected randomly* ... I hope that is not per sock ...

Comment: I haven't gotten a single bit of SWAG, looking forward to having more swag than @Snow s pup. ;-}

Comment: SO has historically been abysmal at managing swag deliveries and the last we heard it was discontinuing it because of the cost and the persistent failure to manage it properly. Has something changed internally?

Comment: [Am I eligible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304059/1944896) ? ^^

Comment: Aww. My main account hit 300k in May 2019 so it's unlikely I hit 250k after March 2019. Definitely never got swag for it though. Guess I miss out :(

Comment: Yeah looks like it happened around Feb 2018. Is there a reason for the big gap in eligibility?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Anyone who hit the milestone at that time should have gotten swag via the previous process. This process is meant to cover everyone who became eligible after we stopped sending it out. If you never got any emails about it before, you probably had emails for Community Milestones turned off.

Comment: First decision of the company for looong time with which I 1000% agree. Thumbs up.

Comment: @Richard IIRC SWAG shipping was previously done by SE employees themselves. From this question I take that they have now outsourced this to a dedicated fulfilment provider.

Comment: @rene You get the second sock at 200k. Incentive!

Comment: @rene you already have a sock: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/269324/kennybot so one of them definitely matches.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354799/230855#comment1185546_354802) [links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354799/230855#comment1186638_354802)?

Comment: @Machavity Getting a sock to 200k? Even the bears of Security SE haven't managed that yet.

Comment: @animuson does the user need to have got 100k new points between March 2019 and December 2020? Could they have earned 99k before March 2019 and 1k after March 2019?

Comment: What about 500K?

Comment: Great to hear about this!!! you know I only became moderator for a mug... that I don't see on the list.. you just brake my heart!!!! :) (jokes asides, this is great)....

Comment: @gbianchi unfortunately our swag supplier can only send mugs in quantities of 40 at a time, so unless you have a cafe, probably more than appropriate.

Comment: @Catija I will convince Gervasio to make a metting in his house (?) :p

Comment: Not that I'm anywhere near either of those rep requirements (XD), but is that total across all of the SE network, or would one need to have 100k/250k on a single site?

Comment: @ifconfig it's per site. Sorry.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Check your email for the text `Congratulations for hitting a quarter-million points on Stack Overflow` ... if you see this, then check the date.  That you never received swag means that you _did_ get the notification, but did not get sent anything.  I got this email back in April, 2019.

Comment: As per a previous conversation... could someone send Tim Post a pair of socks? :D

Comment: Amazing, faith restored in SE management. The previous announcement to discontinue swag came after all the fudgestorm of last year and felt a bit spiteful

Comment: Do we need to activate "Community Milestones" email notifications now to get this email?

Comment: Been contributing to Stack Overflow for over 10 years now and still only at 32K rep  How do people find the time to get 100K, 250K, plus reps with a full-time job…?

Comment: @MartinBean Just post ten complete answers a day, including the highest possible quality answer on every single bountied question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It seems I have those emails turned off. Either I didn't realise that, or I didn't expect it to be the only channel by which such things would be presented to me. Either way I've missed out. But glad all those who reached it later are getting something.

Comment: If it were available for sale, I would lose all interest in it.

Comment: @852172 It's a thing that adheres to the back of a smart phone making it easier to hold and can act as a prop for setting the phone on a surface. https://www.popsockets.com/

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I believe simply turning on that email bucket again will trigger the Congrats email to be sent the next time the script checks for eligible candidates, which should drop you into the bucket of "people sent the email while we weren't sending swag." The script only checks that you are above the threshold and *haven't received the email before* not that you just recently passed the threshold.

Comment: I didn't get swag because you weren't shipping to Russia at the moment; I assume you still don't?

Comment: The swag is great, and I am glad it can't be purchased. Its scarcity makes it feel more valuable.

Comment: For what it is worth, I would be willing to pay for  shipping costs, if that can help in my case.

Comment: As someone who is rather new to the StackExchange-Community I have no idea what this swag-thing is about. At first glimpse I thought it is about the [SourceWare Archive Group (SWAG) and about the programming language Pascal](http://www.retroarchive.org/swag/index.html).  But it seems to be about clothing.  ;-)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek or a new set of keys?

Comment: Do moderators of Beta sites also get swag?

Comment: What sizes are the t-shirts going to be available in?

Comment: @DavidG All three sizes — S, XS, and XXS — of course! But since I have no idea what a Pop Socket is even after looking at the photo of it, I choose to assume it's a shrinkwrap t-shirt applicator tool. They thought of everything!

Comment: @FeRD Pop socket is a thing you stick on the back of your mobile phone so you can take selfies.

Comment: @DavidG The answer is XS - XXL. Standard American T-Shirt sizing.

Comment: @Catija Boo, one size too small :(

Comment: Constructive criticism: The SO socks are a great design, but the SE ones just look like a plain set of Blue-striped socks that one could buy from pretty much any dept. store. Please consider a redesign once the current stock is cleared - perhaps one that uses the SE logo directly (similar to the SO design?)

Comment: What about the nature of the fabric and brands of the clothing, are they ethically sourced? I understand the prices can't be too high, but I'm not sure if the alternative would be a very welcome token of appreciation.

Comment: @animuson How often does the script run? I had the emails set off so never got it when I passed 100k on SFF and turned it back on a couple of days ago. As far as I can tell I haven't had the email come through yet.

Comment: Two questions, is there an SEDE query I can run to show the users on our site, via a meta post, who should be eligible. Are you taking into account how much bounty was given? I'm just a tiny amount off, but I'm sure someone else might become eligible if they had, say 75k rep, but had given >25k in bounties?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I honestly have no idea, I'd guess within 24 hours. But your account says you were sent the email on March 28.

Comment: @animuson I must have missed it somehow, I'm assuming that I don't need the old email anymore though and it's going to be based on new ones being sent out regardless of what happened with the old one?

Comment: hot take: this is better than hats!

Comment: Am I the only one who read "sock puppet" instead of "pop socket"? (I guess we can convert the socks into sock puppets.)

Comment: Guess I missed my swag email back in the old days when I hit 100K. Not sure why one would use email and not a notification on the site.

Comment: Whatever happened to the users promised swag for their contributions three or four years ago during christmas.  I believe JNet was in charge of that.  Users were asked to offer, in answers, the good deeds they had done of the Holidays?

Comment: @amWhy I think you're talking about this: [Announcing Our Amazing 2018 Stuff-A-Way!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321399/223467) aren't you?

Comment: @Mureinik  Yes indeed, that's the one! ;-)

Comment: Is this only for SO, or other sites too?

Comment: May we ask what the rough timeline for rolling this out would be?

Comment: Isn't this in contrast with the site's goal of being non-profit?

Comment: @EtackSxchange We have no goals to be non-profit.

Comment: Just wish swag was available to the smaller communities too! [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) will probably forever remain swagless with a hard 100k requirement, instead of one calculated based on the size of user base or site's activity.

Comment: 100k/250k shall be a sum of reputation **across** all the StackExchange sites or of just **one** particular one (StackOverflow...)?

Comment: What about new contributor!!?? Specially, I need more swag to be great SE, SO member I need T-shirt 

Comment: The qualifying bar is way out of reach for me.....guess just gotta look at them and be content

Comment: @Catija - is the per site only absolute? [Swag for non-SO folks - a couple of thoughts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358709/154443)

Comment: @Catija: So I have [180k](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/85546.png) but don't qualify because I'm active in multiple communities? :(

Comment: Has it been confirmed that this requires 100k on a single site, not 100k across the network?

Comment: I found an identical SO T-shirt in a second hand store :P

Comment: Now I don't remember when I got 100k on https://movies.stackexchange.com/, but surely there was no swag involved.

Comment: I anticipate to hit 100k in 2yrs. Will the swag still be there in 2 years? 

Comment: Will you also go through people who were supposed to get swag but never got it? I believe I was on the "6 to 8 weeks" list for taking the Developer Pre-Survey 2017 or something else from that era. Or I suppose there's no "official" list anywhere?

Comment: @amWhy I got a box - took a while, but who cares. My coworkers used to cast jealous glances at my water bottle, back then when we saw each other f2f.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on what the "first wave" contains, and on what the timeline is for further waves? We're approaching the six-month mark after this was posted.

Comment: The packages will go out in waves - there's too many recipients to include all at the same time so we're breaking the total list into different sections. Wave 1 contains the first recipients. We email them and get their responses. Then, the items are shipped to them. We'll then continue with the next waves. There's a total of 3 waves for the year.

Comment: @JuanM I have contacted "contact us" about this but haven't got a response yet. Do past moderators who did not get their initial swag shipment get swag even though they are no longer mods anymore?

Comment: @Xnero We did get your message and responded. Maybe it was just missed? Yes, you will be added to the list of mods who will get swag along with other moderators who did not get their packages either.

Comment: @JuanM Seems like I missed it, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Is it gone again? All I got for earning 250K, is a “congratulations” e-email.

Comment: @Holger Swag is not gone! Your name has gone into a list and you'll be contacted about this once we get through the current backlog. Thanks for your patience on this, we're getting through that backlog as fast as we can. And yes, "Congratulations!" on this achievement. That's quite a milestone.

Comment: @JuanM Out of curiosity, do you have a similar list for the 1M milestone?

Comment: @VonC We're working on that as we speak!! We have not forgotten you. ;)

Comment: @JuanM that’s great news. Thanks. One conclusion is that it would improve the communication to include something along “we’ll contact you again” in the mail. I suppose, we all have experience with processing backlogs…

Comment: [My 100k swag arrived yesterday.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411242/874188) The socks are slightly different from what's in the presentation above. I reached 100k on Stack Overflow in the summer of 2020 and received the swag order form in August 2021.

Comment: Recently received  it for [Movies & TV 100k rep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIPR4.jpg)

Comment: @JuanM I was elected a mod in 2019 (biology.SE), and I *still* have never received or been contacted about getting mod swag. :'(. Even my spam folder has been waiting for that email all these long months :p! Any chance I can still get anything?? A mod hat and Nalgene would be cool :D And/or socks.

Comment: @theforestecologist Let me look into this for you. In the meantime, please send a message about this using the Contact Us form and I'll have that ticket assigned to me.

Comment: @JuanM Even I have achieved 100K threshold on SO but have never received or been contacted about getting 100K swag

Comment: @undetectedSelenium The list for the 100K and 250K users is very long! Your name will be coming up in a future wave. Thanks for your continued patience!

Comment: Thanks @JuanM! I just hit 100K, so I guess I can wait a little longer and some swag will come?

Comment: @JuanM [It's disappointing to see the complete lack of movement on this after more than six-to-eight *months*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358319/184688). Any updates on when the status might change?

Comment: @V2Blast Upon closer inspection, it seems my comment just now was mis-addressed -- the hold on swag has been in place for so long that the original poster no longer works for SO, right?

Comment: @E.P.: Yes, Juan left the company earlier this year. See Rosie's update from May 2022 at the top of the post for the latest status on this issue.

Comment: @V2Blast Please understand where I'm coming from -- the initial posting of this thread did a lot to mend frayed SO-community relations and create goodwill, but from where I am standing this goodwill is not just evaporating, it's souring. My previous comments show I am clearly aware of the May 2022 update (so it is hard to read a pointer to that update as anything other than insulting) and that I am disappointed that nothing has happened in the seven months since it was posted. Is there really *nothing* to report regarding what the timeline is for the next status change?

Comment: Hiring a merchandising intern to open a web shop and manage this plus that would solve this problem for you. It would cost ~$20/hour and 15-30 minutes of supervisor time a month approving the intern's merch designs, and would pay for itself.

Comment: @TylerH. On the one hand it's never that simple. On the other, we're being told where to shove it. Whether you like the fact that it's being done nicely is up to you :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Things are rarely as simple as they sound. In this case, it actually is. Online merch shops and distribution is a _thoroughly_ solved problem and has been for over a decade.

Comment: The addition of updates inconsistently above and below the original post gets progressively more confusing with each new update. They should all be above, or all below. Or better yet, the updates should probably have been made as their own post instead... Especially one clarifying that no part of the original announcement is relevant at this point since it's indefinitely paused. (If there is more news about swag coming back in the future, it should definitely be a new post.)

Comment: @TylerH I think we're reading it the same way :)

Comment: I find it insane that even half-baked youtubers with their mon and a dog as staff can make swag without much trouble, yet a huge company like Stack Overflow can't get this right.

Comment: @T.Sar To give a little bit of credit, it's easy to do swag– it's much harder (comparatively) to do _good_ / "not crap" promo swag. I don't blame them for seemingly wanting to do it well; it's just frustrating that this is yet another area of promises that something is being worked on, only to be "indefinitely paused" sometime down the line. The lack of commitment to project, especially community-centric ones, is very tiring.

Answer (score 133):

Great news, thanks a lot!

Since the discontinuation of swag, we have had a few users reach a new milestone, [1 million reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all). Are there any plans to extend the swag packages for exceptional users like them?

And (I'm not sure how deep your pockets are) it's perhaps time to award users who are not so much into collecting reputation but doing [a lot of dirty work in the review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats)?

Comment: I dunno. Jon Skeet still has [the greatest swag ever](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/01/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/)

Comment: I know there are several users who give away many bounties, like three of 500 rep at the same time and almost always a few running. Those users will not reach new milestones but should feel appreciation.

Comment: One way to address these active users that spend reputatioin is to add the rep spent on bounties (and possibly other voluntary rep costs, like downvoting answers) to the total rep and check that against the swag threshold.

Comment: can we have the option of foregoing the normal swag tiers if we're promised a portrait of a unicorn at 1 mill? :D

Comment: @Willeke I always thought it would be nice to have a badge for 10 bounties or something like that

Comment: Plans for swag can always be updated and we'd love to be able to provide more in the future. For now, we'll focus on the folks mentioned in the post and once we can fulfill those, we can start discussions on additional categories.

Comment: Yes, there are plans in the works for the 1M milestone. More to come soon!

Comment: It's 2023 and still no news...

Answer (score 52):

### Please help us choose T-shirt sizes

I got a SO T-shirt [in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303045/2586922). I chose XL size, and it turned out to be too large for me, so I never could wear it.

I don't want to make a similar mistake again. So I'm asking:

- What is the manufacturer now? If it is the same as with my old T-shirt I can safely assume I want size L.
- Preferably, can you provide T-shirt **width** and **length** measurements (cm or inches) for each size name (L, XL, ...)? Actual sizes vary a lot across countries and manufacturers, so it's hard to choose just based on the size name.

Comment: The exact brand tended to vary with the old black shirts. White shirts were seriously less popular so I think they had one brand as far as I can remember.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks. I have edited my post according to that

Comment: i got one too, too large (m) and i am not getting one again, even pasting 300k this year and 250k too early this year ...

Comment: @NinaScholz We should organize some sort of T-shirt exchange among users with the wrong size :-)

Comment: Yeah, I have this problem a lot, too - M is great sometimes, but other times it's horribly small.

Comment: As someone who handled swag in the past, this was always a huge struggle. New shirts would often get printed on whatever was the cheapest option available at the time, which meant that pretty much every shirt we had before was slightly different in size from others. I have multiple different shirts from SO and other sites, and none of them fit the same as another. So it's not as much the need for publishing shirt sizes, but **finding one shirt manufacturer you like and sticking with it**. Changing between them freely only leads to these odd problems.

Comment: Also, shirt sizes are gendered. I take a different size in men's than in women's. It seems from the form that only men's are available: it just says S M L etc with no gender. This should definitely be fixed. I can sort of handle choosing which size of men's shirt I want (I'm used to it) but I hate the erasure that forgets there is another style of shirt - you know, half the planet?

Comment: Tee shirts are pretty straight-forward to modify to size-down.  Easier with a sewing machine - my hand sewing isn't neat enough.  1) iron it flat, inside out.  Draw a line up the side, and curve it to clip the armpit, then down the underside of the sleeve to the cuff.  2) Switch it up and back down with a colour-matched thread and a short stitch length.  3) Optionally trim off most of the folded-over flap with scissors/shears.  4) Optionally stitch the flap flat to the cloth.

Comment: @Criggie I'm not that good at sewing, but hopefully this will help others!

Answer (score 41):

#### Much appreciated

This feels like another very important step in the right direction of rebuilding trust. We get that swag is a pain in the arse to manage, logistically. But such an important gesture of goodwill.

#### What does "or" mean?

> Branded t-shirt (SE or SO)

Does this mean:

- recipient chooses which t-shirt they want
- you get an SO t-shirt if you hit a rep milestone on SO, otherwise SE?
- chosen randomly?

Comment: Good question - I think we will likely default to the second one but I don't know if there's a reason we couldn't go with the first one. If someone wants an SO shirt but got their rep elsewhere, it seems reasonable to let them choose... and if someone already has an SO shirt when they get to 250k, maybe they'd rather an SE shirt. Thanks for asking!

Comment: *"But such an import gesture of goodwill."* Don't forget that it's also very good for the company. People out there wearing t-shirts, having mugs sitting on their desk, etc., are all marketing for the product.

Answer (score 35):

### Update November 2023

... I guess, at least, now you are honest about it?

I am having quite some trouble processing just how cavalierly of a fashion you guys break direct promises of doing nice things. I imagine that there could be individuals within the institution that actually care, but that *does not matter*. These are institutional actions, and what your institutional actions say is that *you just don't care*.

Also, I should note, the line "Hint: sometimes involves swag", which is by now little more than active mockery, is still present in the Community Milestones toggle in the email settings. **At least be brave enough to take that down.**

---

### Edit

so.... this is really, really not one of those things where you can say "finally, we're doing this good thing again!" and not do it. Folks, you promised swag **two years ago**, and you took it away again, and now you've been **silent for eight months** about when the swag might actually be delivered. If you're going to backtrack and cancel it, and we should just write it off, then at least let us know.

---

**Original post** from when I was happy about this:

---

**This is very good to hear!** particularly given that this promise

> [image]

turns out to have been hollow for the better part of two years.

---

Seriously, though.

I passed the total-100k threshold quite some time ago, but I chose to approach the formal 100k-rep threshold more slowly through giving away substantial rep in bounties. However, this intentional approach was hijacked, and I crossed 100k in November 2019 as a result of the [re-setting of the question upvote value from 5 to 10 rep](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/). Regardless of the merits of that decision, it was an arbitrary change to the basics of the Q&A engine which was done with utterly no community consultation, coming at a time when [things were not going well and this kind of unilateral action was obviously a problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper).

So the company takes away my choice for the moment, and, on top of that, instead of the swag that was promised, all I get is a canned email? I'm sorry to say that this felt distinctly like getting spat at in the face.

**Thank you for taking steps to mend this.** I'm not sure that my trust in SE, and your handling of the platform, is back up at levels where I would feel comfortable wearing the t-shirt in public (and indeed my t-shirt from [this glorious artwork](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304880/184688)* is currently languishing in a shelf), but I'll think about it.

---

<sup>*speaking of which -- our site is *still* a hat, and we *still* don't have our site-hat hat. Just sayin'.</sup>

Comment: I never got anything.

Answer (score 33):

Are there any per-site swag items (such as t-shirts), or just network and SO?

A lot of the previous swag was branded for that specific site; for instance, I have a t-shirt with the Science Fiction & Fantasy logo, some Movies & TV stickers, and a Super User pen. Is there anything like this with the new swag provider, or just the SE and SO generic branded swag?

Comment: At this point in time, it's just going to be SE and SO. We love the SE sites and their vibrant designs and swag but the overhead of printing and storing the swag for all of the sites really caught up with us and it gets pretty expensive. I proudly wear my M&TV shirt on a regular basis and have various SE stickers all over my laptop but... sad to say, that's not something we can bring back.

Comment: Alas, I guess that makes my SU T shirts a collector's item. Though they're probably going to get worn to the point they get fall apart :(

Answer (score 19):

> Those who earned these levels starting from March 2019

### How do you measure when a reputation threshold was reached?

I ask because of the big reputation recalculation in November 2019, when question upvotes were changed from 5 to 10 reputation. Since the change was retroactive, it means that some users *actually* passed the 100k threshold on that day but everything in the reputation tracking system shows that they passed it many months earlier.

[Here's an example](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1148/jack-b-nimble) of such a user. On his [reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/2706/jack-b-nimble?tab=reputation) it looks like he broke the 100k barrier in February 2019 (before the March watershed), but in reality he broke it suddenly from the rep recalc in [November 2019](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/58631?m=52549603#52549603), along with a few other users.

I hope you've already thought of this and will calculate the "time of earning" in a way that doesn't accidentally disenfranchise users such as this one. But I wanted to mention it explicitly *just in case* by some oversight you're using e.g. the reputation graph to check when the 100k and 250k thresholds were passed.

Comment: Time of reaching the threshold is calculated based on when the congratulations email is sent and has nothing really to do with when they perceivably passed the threshold. That email is sent in batches to all users who meet the criteria: 1) Currently above the threshold (100k or 250k); 2) Has the Community Milestones bucket enabled in their email settings; 3) Hasn't received the email for that milestone in the past. We are just looking at the date the email was generated and recorded to their user history. Anything else would be too complicated.

Comment: @animuson Thanks. I thought so, just wanted to confirm.

Comment: @animuson - sorry, you have now confused me even more. I got the email after March 2019, but no swag. Does that mean I won't be getting swag because I got hte email?

Comment: @DVK Everyone's still getting the email, even without swag. AIUI, if you got the email after March 2019, then you're eligible.

Comment: @DVK We removed mentions of swag from the email in March 2019 because we weren't sending it, so we used that date as a timeline for... we're going to pull everyone who received the email since we stopped swag stuff and re-contact them about swag.

Comment: @animuson: I didn't realize I needed the "community milestone" setting turned on to qualify for swag. I just turned it on. Can I still get the email?

Comment: @einpoklum It should send you the email next time the scheduled task runs for them. It just selects all eligible users who haven't received the email yet.

Answer (score 19):

> Unfortunately, we are unable to offer swag for purchase at this time. If this changes, we will let you know.

I would very much prefer that the same items are ***never for sale***.
Don't take away what's special about them.
You can always create separate merchandise if people want some of that.

BTW, 100k, 250k ...
What about 500k, 1000k?

Comment: Not to burst your bubble, but these items are already not specific to these milestones. They are the same items that are taken to conventions and events and given away to whomever stops by the booths to get one.

Comment: There goes my bubble.

Comment: What animuson says is true for the SO swag but the SE swag is for this only at this point - we don't generally take SE swag to conventions and events. That's not to say that will always be the case but, for now, it is.

Comment: When one bubble bursts, another bubble opens! Or so they say. :)

Answer (score 15):

What a great update, and I hope to be eligible one day as well.

#### One question comes to mind:

Are (former) employees exempt from receiving swag?

Some have gathered tremendous amounts of reputation during their time working at Stack Overflow inc., but disallowing them swag feels wrong, especially seeing the tremendous time some spent on these sites daily. That probably was far more than their contractual 6-8 hours.

Comment: It's worth being aware that, as employees, we get a lot of swag as it is.

Comment: Congratulations I guess @Catija ;)

Comment: Don't get me wrong... I'll be making doe eyes at whoever holds the keys to give me a new mod hat. ;)

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest linking this meta post in the emails.

I got one today and was rather concerned since I've no familiarity with stackoverflowsolutions as a domain and thought it was a phishing attempt, until I found this post.

Comment: The email triggered a few phishing warnings for me including the new domain and the paragraph *"You will be responsible for all taxes or duties owed on the package. We cannot cover any fees incurred by local Customs offices or local taxes. By filling out this form, you agree to pay any fees associated with your package’s receipt."*

Answer (score 11):

I reached the 100k target on Music-Practice and Theory a couple of years ago, but never claimed my swag, for several reasons. Is that still available?

Comment: [This comment from animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back?cb=1#comment1196672_358195) indicates that, if you turn the notification option on, you will receive the email and be eligible. If you already received the email but ignored it, you might need to reach out to staff separately.

Comment: @CodyGray where is that notification option?

Comment: @AnkitSharma It's one of the email settings, on your profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/1311977 ("Community Milestones: Notifications about bounties, reputation and more. Hint: sometimes involves swag.")

Answer (score 10):

I just received a swag email and have responded to it. I have a couple of things I'd like to point out:

- The email came from `stackoverflowsolutions`, which is unfamiliar and raised a red flag for me. Lots of false domains have prefixes or suffixes added to legitimate domain names. Upon investigation, it's legit and appears to be associated with Teams and possibly others. **Edit**: *While I was typing this* the question itself was edited to address this point.
- In the approximately twelve and a half years I've been active on SO, etc., I have been offered swag bundles at least twice before (and well before the ~2019 swag "pause") and have submitted my shipping address and then never received anything. In contrast, I have received the odd individual tshirt or sticker pack a few times. If I receive a bundle this time I will be surprised and pleased. But if it never arrives I will just `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` and move on.

*Update:* Swag received 2021-06-07. Nice items (I received the 250K package minus the stickers and socks)! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

As an owner of a previous generation Server Fault T-shirt, I am a bit disappointed not to see SF or SU represented here. Please consider bringing them back.

Additionally I would like to be able to choose between SO and SE swag, rather than have that choice made for me.

Answer (score 8):

- 2021.10.19: Received email. Thanks everyone.

This is welcome news! Question

### Does this include beta sites?

@filbranden and I were elected to the [Vi & Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com) moderator team, and I haven't received any mail (perhaps my timeline is wrong?). I did see some comments about having community emails enabled, which I do.

Comment: IIUC the mails for newly elected moderators have not gone out just yet. From what I can tell you should be getting swag

Answer (score 7):

To be honest, I'd prefer that recipients would have the opportunity to donate the value of any swag to some charitable organization. My preference would be something related to say world health or hunger.

The honor is nice, but times are desperate.

Perhaps a few organizations could be chosen and recipients could choose one.

Comment: Exactly right.  The world does not need more pointless nerd swag as we sleep-walk into this global environmental crisis.  Hacktoberfest offered the option to plant a tree instead of receiving a t-shirt.  Recognition is welcome but please find a more ethically and environmentally responsible approach.

Comment: The option would be nice yes. But a T-shirt is dwarfed by the effort to reach e.g. 100k, which is basically voluntary work. I personally would like to have something physical to remind myself of that, once I get there (2 accounts at almost 80k+, some time to go).

Answer (score 6):

#### Are the reputation thresholds per-site or network-wide?

Some people specialize in one thing, while others participate on a variety of different sites.  Ideally, it'd be nice to reward both.

Are these jacks of all trades eligible for swag if they cross the threshold across all sites (perhaps excluding association bonuses), or must the threshold be crossed on a single site?

Comment: [Per site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back?cb=1#comment1196499_358195).

Comment: I have asked: [Swag for non-SO folks - a couple of thoughts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358709/154443)

Answer (score 6):

I think there's a bug somewhere. I got a mail from `Community Swag • communityswag@stackoverflowsolutions.com` that I'm getting swag:

> You’re receiving this email because you've either achieved 100K reputation this year or since March 2019.

However, [I've 100K on only one site: Ask Ubuntu](https://stackexchange.com/users/1042873/muru?tab=accounts), where I reached 100K in 2017. I did get the congratulatory email in 2017 and the swag as well (t-shirt, stickers - dispatched October 13, 2017).

Possible causes of error:

- I was suspended for a while, so I wonder if that had something to do with this.
- I was a pro-tem mod on Vi & Vim.
- I reached 250k total rep across SE sites sometime in the past year.
- I got some other swag (a watch for [Time for some more swag!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318910/270345)) in 2019.

---

(Of course, I'd love more swag, but still….)

Comment: I guess I'll submit the form anyway and see what happens.

Comment: You don't know how important 10/13/2017 is to me, and many others. Thank you for sharing that date. LOL! You posted this answer 3 years to-the-day later.

Answer (score 2):

Any news on the design launch Top User Swag for pending sites?

There used to be swag for the design launch of graduate sites in past. But it seems to be not in place lately. Is there any news for that too?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no plan to create any site-specific swag other than for SO.

Comment: @Catija is correct. We're only able to offer SE and SO specific swag at the moment. I'm hopeful this can change in the future and I'll be happy to update if it does!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like [swag is being distributed](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/matthewjbohn24_soflowstate-ugcPost-6980936110562582528-j0Wg) at [Flow State](https://flowstate.stackoverflow.co/).

Still paused here, though?