# My "network reputation" graph does not accurately reflect my accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-graph

Today I noticed that when I look at the reputation graph on my profile, I don't even belong to most of the sites it is showing. My highest reputation sites are not shown at all.

This is me:

[image]

This is not me:

[image]

Comment: Seems a change earlier today that reworked how stackexchange.com looks up Sites broke this. It is finding incorrect sites and skipping those it fails to find. Looks to be broken for all users barring Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange profiles.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

**IT WAS ME!** I'm sorry. I broke it. But I fixed it too!

We're working on migrating some bits of stackexchange.com over (legacy things) and on [debugging some production issues](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1339700309497659392), changing queries and interfaces here, and also on removing cruft. In the reputation tag specifically, not quite correctly.

For anyone curious, stackexchange.com in a galaxy far, far away didn't have access to our main Sites database. As a result, it has its own concept of a `SiteId`. This is a never-ending pain in the rear that we're going to finally get out of existence early next year. Why? Because *things like this* can happen. So we're working on eliminating all the legacy here to improve live and reduce the chance for bugs.

Comment: Thanks! I promise, it never crossed my mind it was related to a nefarious attempt to deny me my swag https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back?cb=1