# My reputation graph does not show my accounts

Tags: bug

Umm... this was closed as a duplicate to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358239/my-network-reputation-graph-does-not-accurately-reflect-my-accounts), but, A. That question never got any answers and B. In my particular case, it is showing physical fitness as my account when it is not. It would be helpful if the closers commented with reasoning to help explain why this question was closed.

On my reputation graph, the graph is tracking physical fitness SE, even though I don't have an account there. It is not tracking any of my actual sites with 200+ reputation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This duplicate is exactly what you are asking, and the comment by SE staff indicates perfectly what's going on. The wording of the auto-comment is indead a bit confusing, as it asks if something answers your question.