# Swag for non-SO folks - a couple of thoughts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, swag

The [return of swag post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358195/154443) is very welcome, however I see a couple of tiny things that we could perhaps improve.

- In the early years of Security.SE, giving sec.SE t-shirts to speakers at conferences and competition winners really drove positive awareness and growth, and I know getting t-shirts from other sites kickstarted my forays out to bicycles.SE, lego.SE etc. I see from [@Catija's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back?cb=1#comment1196455_358232) that this swag run is only going to be SE/SO due to costs/logistics, and there is no current intention to offer swag for purchase.

  But it should be possible for this to be federated out - the logos exist, and small run printers abound in many countries, so could the management of smaller-scale swag for non-trilogy sites be handled by moderators of those sites?
- My other thought is for users who haven't hit 100k or 250k on one site, but have a total rep across multiple sites (yes, I count myself in this group: over 250k across the network, but no more than 60k on any one site). Will there be a "Masters of None" swag package?

Comment: 100k on some sites is kinda unheard off too. Look at the stats for SharePoint for example - requirements should be per site, or just take "top-n users"

Comment: What I feel like is a reasonable compromise might be periodic site-swag drops . I'd also point out that 2/3+1 of the trilogy in 4 parts has no site swag

Comment: @SPArcheon Agreed. I mod on three sites. Total number of >100k users: 2

Comment: I already suggested e-coupons for prizes  and a Logo Printer to print, store, and ship (leaving SE only to send an email and collect a check); but the CM must have tired of comments on their 'no more swag' post and mass-deleted it along with the rest.