# If the mug is gone, could there by some kind of hard physical token of the 100K achievement?

Tags: discussion, swag

My 100K moment is coming up soon. For many years I was looking forward to the mug, mainly because - unlike T shirts or socks - the mug is something I can have on my desk permanently as a reminder of my journey as a programmer, from someone who thought they weren't good enough to be a programmer, to someone who creates software for a living.

[Per this answer, I  know swag is getting a revamp](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back-temporarily-paused) - is the mug gone forever? **If the mug is gone, could there by some kind of hard physical token of the achievement?**

Thanks. I hope it doesn't come off like I feel entitled, it's just that StackOverflow has been a big part of my life for over a decade and it would be very, very special to have some kind of physical reminder of that.

Comment: Do this and call it art https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/bronze-feet-socks-nino-longobardi-room-castel-del-monte-pictured-sculpture-norte-pays-tribute-to-101966109.jpg :)

Comment: Maybe a *coaster* to keep your mug on? [Dark theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFsuN.png) | [Light theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT6DN.png)

Comment: If SE was looking at expanding swag types, which they aren't [challenge coins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge_coin) feel like a reasonable idea. Its a small, cheap to store and ship piece of swag

Comment: The mug is gone? Were you mugged? :)

Comment: You could also have a t-shirt framed, and hang it on your wall.

Comment: I agree the mug is nice. Got one for my mod swag long time ago and I still use it. The nice part about it was it was a large format's one.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek a challenge coin would be lovely - easy to ship, beautiful and those of us who feel proud can have it framed. 

Comment: @Laurel they stopped shipping them cause the new distributor only does mugs in bulk, and shipping ONE mug is not an option.

Comment: Need some way to do bulk to local distributors, who are happy then to batch up orders to individuals.

Comment: IMHO a mug is a bad idea. All of my mugs break after a few years.

Comment: @SurpriseDog I have mugs both at home and at work for 20+ years. ;-)

Comment: I hit 100k a few months back. I'd love some kind of physical memento (although I certainly realize SO has no obligation to provide one). I feel similar to you though - SO has been a massive, irreplaceable part of my life as a developer, and it's hard not to get somewhat sentimental about it.