# Why do Stack Exchange users want to get upvoted? Are they rewarded for that?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, up-votes

Why do Stack Exchange users compete to get votes or points?

- Just for the pleasure of doing it?
- For public recognition?
- To get job offers?
- Do they receive money or gifts for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do they receive money or gifts for it?

No. Nobody except Stack Exchange staff gets paid. Not even ♦ moderators

> No, the moderators on this site are elected volunteers.

From [this meta history SE question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4364/54750)

You do get [swag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358195/1117855) for getting to 100k, 250k or a ♦ moderator. Though it has been on pause since May of 2022. But compared to the amount of time to get to a single one of those, it's easier to get a job and earn the money for the shirt, pop socket, etc. than by answering and asking questions.

---

> Just for the pleasure of doing it?

Yes, that's exactly why. We like helping others and we do it here on Stack Exchange. Some may do it on forums or Discord servers, but we do it here.

---

> To get job offers?

Just for answering questions? No. It could help you get a job, but this itself won't. If your employer sees you have made many high quality answers, it could probably help you get a job, but no more than other things.

---

> For public recognition?

There basically is none. Unless a person already goes to Stack Exchange, they will never know you exist, and will still not know you exist if you use a pseudonym.

Comment: I have great spelling I meant `pop socket`

Comment: A fun read related to the mods not being paid point: [Is Stack Exchange in violation of New York labor law, in using volunteer moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337117/997587)

Comment: @starball is interesting never knew. Though thats off-topic for this question